# How to refresh the selection box when new option is added in Django?

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys

I have a form with a selection box related to a foreign key (for example, category). And on the same page, I have another link that opens a new page to add a new instance of the foreign key. Once the new instance is added, how can I update the current form to add the new option, and preserve the text in the text field (just like how the admin page behaves)?

Here are some of my code snippets:

update_post.html:

```
...
<form method="post" novalidate action='.'>
{% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'base_form.html' with form=form %}
    # button to add a category
    <a href="{% url 'blog:create_category' %}?next={{ request.path }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" target="_blank">{% trans "Add category" %}</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="publish" value={% trans 'Publish' %}>{% trans 'Publish' %}</button>
</form>
...
```

create_category.html:

```
...
<form action="./{% if request.GET %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}{% endif %}" method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'base_form.html' with form=form %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value={% trans 'Create' %}>{% trans 'Create' %}</button>
</form>
...
```

views.py:

```
...
class PostUpdate(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    success_url = '/'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'category']

class CategoryCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'create_category.html'
    model = Category
    fields = ['name']
    def get_success_url(self):
        if 'next' in self.request.GET:
            return self.request.GET.get('next')
        else:
            return reverse('index')
...
```

What I want to do is that when a new category is added, it becomes available in the update_post page right away, and any changes to the body field are preserved.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this yesterday inspired by django admin ForeignKey popup window add.my condition is a goods has goodcategory and i can add/edit/delet goodscategory in goods's add/update view and the result add/edit/delet goodcategory will sync to goods's add/update view.Here is a demo,which popup is support by [layui](http://www.layui.com/).
[image]
[image]
as you can see i can add\change\delete ForeignKey without refresh the parent page.

first custom a new Field to ForeignKey which will receieve add_url\update_url\delete_url:

```
class ForeignKeyWidget(Select):
    template_name = 'widgets/foreign_key_select.html'

    def __init__(self, url_template, *args, **kw):
        super(ForeignKeyWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # Be careful that here "reverse" is not allowed
        self.url_template = url_template

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super(ForeignKeyWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context['add_url'] = self.url_template
        context['update_url'] = self.url_template
        context['delete_url'] = self.url_template + 'lang_delete/'
        return context
```

second is custom a widget for your custom field which can popup add/update category windows and use ajax to delete category:

foreign_key_select.html:

```
{% include "django/forms/widgets/select.html" %}

    <style>
        #{{ widget.attrs.id }}_add, #{{ widget.attrs.id }}_change, #{{ widget.attrs.id }}_delete {
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            height: 25px;
            line-height: 25px;
        }
    </style>

    <a class="layui-btn layui-btn-mini" id="{{ widget.attrs.id }}_add">
        add
    </a>
    <a class="layui-btn layui-btn-mini layui-btn-disabled" id="{{ widget.attrs.id }}_change">
        change
    </a><a class="layui-btn layui-btn-mini layui-btn-disabled" id="{{ widget.attrs.id }}_delete">
        delete
    </a>

    <script>
        $('#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_add').click(function () {
            var index = layui.layer.open({
                title: "add_category",
                type: 2,
                area: ['700px', '500px'],
                content: "{{ add_url }}" + '?popup=1&to_field={{ widget.attrs.id }}',
                success: function (layer, index) {

                }
            });
        });

        $("#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_change").click(function () {
            var id = $('#{{ widget.attrs.id }}').val();
            if (id) {
                var index = layui.layer.open({
                    title: "change_category",
                    type: 2,
                    area: ['700px', '500px'],
                    content: '{{ update_url }}' + id + '?popup=1&to_field={{ widget.attrs.id }}',
                    success: function (layer, index) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $("#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_delete").click(function () {
            var id = $('#{{ widget.attrs.id }}').val();
            var value = $('#{{ widget.attrs.id }} option[value=' + id + ']').text();
            var indexGood = value.lastIndexOf('>');
            var valueN = indexGood > 0 ? value.substring(indexGood + 1, value.length) : value;
            if (id) {
                layer.confirm('corform delete' + valueN + ' ?', {icon: 3, title: 'delete'}, function (index) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {},
                        url: '{{ delete_url }}' + id + '/',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
                        },
                        success: function (data, textStatus) {
                            layer.close(index);
                            $('#{{ widget.attrs.id }} option[value=' + data.id + ']').remove();
                            $("#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_change,#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_delete").addClass('layui-btn-disabled');

                            return false;
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            layer.alert('delete failed' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        function {{ widget.attrs.id }}_isDisabled() {
            if ($('#{{ widget.attrs.id }}').val()) {
                $("#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_change,#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_delete").removeClass('layui-btn-disabled');
            } else {
                $("#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_change,#{{ widget.attrs.id }}_delete").addClass('layui-btn-disabled');
            }
        }

        $('#{{ widget.attrs.id }}').change(function () {
            {{ widget.attrs.id }}_isDisabled();
        });

        {{ widget.attrs.id }}_isDisabled();
    </script>
```

third is use your custom field for category in your forms.py:

```
class GoodsForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GoodsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = Goods
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'content']
        widgets = {
            'category': ForeignKeyWidget(url_template=reverse_lazy('goods_category_ajax_create')),
        }
```

and new a goodcategory form is forms.py

```
class GoodsCategoryForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GoodsCategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['cover'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['parent'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = GoodsCategory
        fields = ['name', 'cover', 'parent']
```

four is handle request in your views.py:

```
class GoodsCategoryAjaxCreateView(BaseContextMixin, IsStaffUserMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = GoodsCategoryForm
    template_name = 'goods_category_ajax/create.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if 'to_field' in self.request.GET:
            kwargs['to_field'] = self.request.GET['to_field']
        return super(GoodsCategoryAjaxCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        context = {'op': 'create', 'id': self.object.id, 'value': self.object.__str__()}
        if 'to_field' in self.request.GET:
            context['to_field'] = self.request.GET['to_field']
        return TemplateResponse(self.request, 'goods_category_ajax/success.html', context=context)


    class GoodsCategoryAjaxUpdateView(BaseContextMixin, IsStaffUserMixin, UpdateView):
        model = GoodsCategory
        form_class = GoodsCategoryForm
        slug_field = 'id'
        context_object_name = 'goods_category'
        template_name = 'goods_category_ajax/update.html'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            if 'to_field' in self.request.GET:
                kwargs['to_field'] = self.request.GET['to_field']
            return super(GoodsCategoryAjaxUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save()
            context = {'op': 'create', 'id': self.object.id, 'value': self.object.__str__()}
            if 'to_field' in self.request.GET:
                context['update'] = self.request.GET['to_field']
            return TemplateResponse(self.request, 'goods_category_ajax/success.html', context=context)


    class GoodsCategoryAjaxLangDeleteView(BaseContextMixin, IsStaffUserMixin, FakeDeleteView):
        model = GoodsCategory
        slug_field = 'id'

        def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            data = {'op': 'delete', 'id': self.object.id, 'value': self.object.__str__()}
            self.object.delete()
            return JsonResponse(data=data)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^ajax/$', GoodsCategoryAjaxCreateView.as_view(), name='goods_category_ajax_create'),
url(r'^ajax/(?P<slug>\d+)/$', GoodsCategoryAjaxUpdateView.as_view(), name='goods_category_ajax_update'),
url(r'^ajax/lang_delete/(?P<slug>\d+)/$', GoodsCategoryAjaxLangDeleteView.as_view(),
    name='goods_category_ajax_lang_delete'),
```

five is your add popup windows will open url handle by GoodsCategoryAjaxCreateView and the return template is:

```
{% extends "manage/base.html" %}

{% block main %}

    <form id='goods_category_ajax_create' class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          action="{% url 'goods_category_ajax_create' %}{% if to_field %}?to_field={{ to_field }}{% endif %}"
          method="post">
        {% include 'manage/widgets/form.html' %}

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                <input class="layui-btn layui-btn-normal" type="submit" value="add_category"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

you submit a new category with modelform and createview,when the form is_vaild a success.html will be return by TemplateResponse(as you can see in GoodsCategoryAjaxCreateView form_valid),and the point is success.html is nothing but a script that can close popup window and insert new option to the to_field element in parent window.here is success.html:

```
{% extends "manage/base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <script>
        var to_field = '#{{ to_field }}', op = '{{ op }}', id = '{{ id }}', value = '{{ value }}';
        if (to_field) {
            switch (op) {
                case 'create':
                    if (id) {
                        var index = parent.layer.getFrameIndex(window.name); //get current iFrame index
                        parent.layer.close(index); //close
                        $option = '<option value=' + id + ' selected>' + value + '</option>';
                        $(to_field, window.parent.document).append($option);
                        $(to_field + '_change,' + to_field + '_delete', window.parent.document).removeClass('layui-btn-disabled');
                    }
                    break;
                case 'update':
                    if (id) {
                        var index = parent.layer.getFrameIndex(window.name); 
                        parent.layer.close(index); 
                        $(to_field + ' option[value=' + id + ']', window.parent.document).html(value);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```